# checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener:throw java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: android

Following is the adapter I am using.

Its throwing an exception when I set `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.
I have tried to use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` in my activity directly (without a separate adapter) but still it failed.

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final List<String> list;
private final Activity context;
private final int layOut;

public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context,int rowLayout, List<String> list) {
    super(context, rowLayout , list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.layOut = rowLayout;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(layOut, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.callTitle);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        viewHolder.checkbox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(list.get(position));

    return view;
}

private OnCheckedChangeListener checkListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton checkboxView, boolean isChecked) {

       }
    };
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
holder.checkbox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {

                        }
                    });
```

This works for me.